# Microsoft Word | Adding a word to a numerical field

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

I have a numerical field:

```
SEQ Equation \* ARABIC \s 1
```

I want to sub-sorting specific equations by adding **a**,**b**, and **c**. For example:

> (1.5.**a**)
> (1.5.**b**)
> (1.5.**c**)
> (1.6)
> (1.7)

Is there any trick for it?
Something like this in the MicrosoftWord:

[image: Example image]

Comment: This looks like `Word`-things, but I cannot tell. You might have a  better chance of getting an answer if you fill in some background information and which actual application / situation you are doing this in.

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft Word. Something like this: https://preview.redd.it/rmca91d1jek71.png?width=359&format=png&auto=webp&s=f15c3efdd9187babc34919c2dd9bf47d80a458fa

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a really simple "trick". As background, using simple field coding, you would probably need 3 different field sequences. You should be able to omit the `\* Arabic` switch anyway because `\* Arabic` is the default, but forgetting about the `\s 1` switch for now you would need

A set of fields for the numbers without letters (10,11,12 in your example), e.g.

```
{ SEQ Equation }
```

A set of fields for the first lettered number (13a in your example), e.g.

```
{ SEQ Equation }{ SEQ Letter \r 1 \* alphabetic }
```

A set of fields for each subsequent lettered number (14b in your example), e.g.

```
{ SEQ Equation \c }{ SEQ Letter \* alphabetic }
```

The trouble with that is that if you resequence any of the lettered equations you may have to modify the field sequences (e.g. if you swap "b" and "c" you only have to update the fields, but if you move "b" in front of "a" you have to modify the fields for both "a" and "b". Unless you have hundreds of equations it would probably be simpler to insert the lettered numbers manually without using fields.

You might be able to simplify that if your lettered sequence never went to "c", and/or instead of

```
10
11
12
13a
13b
```

you used

```
10
11
12
12a
12b
```

Otherwise, you can probably use a rather more complex set of fields, but you have to consider whether it is worth your while, and/or maintainability if the document is going to be maintained by others. Using the following sequences, you can get away with two field sequences, one for unlettered numbers and one for lettered numbers, and re-arrangement of the lettered equations should only require field updates. (To modify a lettered to an unlettered equation or vice versa you would still need to change the field coding).

For the unlettered numbers, you could use

```
{ SEQ Equation { SEQ Letter \r 0 \h } }
```

For the lettered numbers, you could use

```
{ SEQ Letter \c \"'{ SEQ Equation \c }';;'{ SEQ "Equatio{ SEQ Letter \c \#;;n}" }'" }{ SEQ Letter \* alphabetic }
```

For that to work, *all* the `{ }` have to be the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 in Windows desktop Word, and you need straight double and single quotation marks where indicated. You might be able to reduce the length a bit (e.g. you can change `{ SEQ something }` to `{SEQ something}`). In particular, you need

```
{ SEQ Letter \c \#;;n}
```

or

```
{ SEQ Letter \c \#";;n" }
```

but not

```
{ SEQ Letter \c \#;;n }
```

which will introduce an extra space.

So how does that lot work? Well, you can doubtless work it out, but I suggest you try it first as the full explanation has a lot of detail you may not really need to know.

```
{ SEQ Letter \ r 0 \h }
```

just ensures that the Letter sequence is 0 at the beginning of each lettered block. By using the \h switch to hide the result, Word doesn't try to treat the result as a bookmark name when you nest it inside the `{ SEQ Equation }` field. But you could use

```
{ SEQ Equation }{ SEQ Letter \r 0 \h }
```

if you prefer.

When you reach a lettered block, all you need is

```
{ SEQ Letter \* alphabetic }
```

to insert the correct letter.

You need to increment the Equation number *once* at the beginning of the block. But you can't do that the obvious way, which would be something like

```
{ IF { SEQ Letter \c } = 0 "{ SEQ Equation }" "{ SEQ Equation \c }" }
```

because when Letter > 0, Word correctly inserts the `{ SEQ Equation \c }` result, but still evaluates the `{ SEQ Equation }` result and increments Equation. This is actually quite difficult to avoid, because the other way you might try to avoid this would be to do something like

```
{ SEQ Equation { IF { SEQ Letter \c } > 0 "\c" "" } }
```

But that just doesn't work either. Tring to do it by manipulating the current value using `\r` is also at least difficult and I suspect is more complex than the approach I am describing.

So what you can do is use something that will cause Word to increment the Equation sequence in the first lettered equations, but increment another sequence ("Equatio" in this case) in all the subsequent lettered equations.

Step by step, the numeric pattern used here

```
{ SEQ number \#"'A';'B';'C'"}
```

has result `A` if number > 0, `B` if number < 0, and `C` if number = 0

The single quotation marks are needed to ensure that the text inside is treated as a literal, not as a pattern. For example, with number = 15,

```
{ SEQ number \#"'0';'B';'C'"}
```

would have result `0` but

```
{ SEQ number \#"0;'B';'C'"}
```

the zero has a special meaning and the result would be `15`. But if you use characters that do not have special meanings you do not need the qotation marks, (and you can sometimes omit the surrounding "" marks too).

So

```
{ SEQ Letter \c \#;;n}
```

has an empty result if Letter > 0 and result '`n`' if Letter = 0.

At the beginning of our first lettered equation, Letter is 0, so

```
{ SEQ "Equatio{ SEQ Letter \c \#;;n}" }
```

will be evaluated as

```
{ SEQ "Equation" }
```

i.e.

```
{ SEQ Equation }
```

but in subsequent lettered equations, Letter > 0 so it is evaluated as

```
{ SEQ Equatio }
```

The full coding of the first field is like this.

{ SEQ Letter \c "'{ SEQ Equation \c }';;'{ SEQ "Equatio{ SEQ Letter \c #;;n}" }'" }

i.e. if Letter is 0, we get the result of

```
{ SEQ "Equatio{ SEQ Letter \c \#;;n}" }
```

which is

```
{ SEQ Equation }
```

(and the { SEQ Equation \c } in the field does not increment Equation).

But in subsequent lettered equations, where Letter > 0, we get the result

```
{ SEQ Equation \c }
```

and the { SEQ Equatio } increments Equatio, not Equation!

Phew!

It's possible that this can be simplified in various ways but that's the best I have been able to manage in Word. Perhaps some other WP has it built-in, or it's easy in TeX or whatever.